# Can't access button inside file 2 when inside template literals

Tags: javascript, html

I can't access this button when I try to access on some other file. It is working when I do it inside first file but not able to do on file 2?
BTW, Css is working fine, if I create a CSS file and add  some styling to the elements, it works, but not the javascript

```js
file1.js
else {
  product_carousel_wrapper.innerHTML = recent.map(productData => 
`
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <button class="click">CTest</button>
  <h1>Bye</h1>
`
).join('');
}
```

```js
file2.js

document.querySelector('.click').addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert('Heyy');
});
```

Comment: `alert('Heyy);` is missing an `'`. Should be `alert('Heyy');`.

Comment: Oh no, that is not a problem, I mistyped it, the problem still arrises

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Any errors in the console?

Comment: its just normal, its inside the template literals, in a map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a listener to the wrapper element and use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) to catch events from child elements that have been added to the DOM dynamically instead of attaching a listener to each button.

```js
// FILE1

// Cache the wrapper
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

// Add the HTML
wrapper.innerHTML = `
  <button>CTest1</button>
  <button>CTest2</button>
  <button>CTest3</button>
`;

// FILE2

// Add a listener to the wrapper
wrapper.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

// Get the textContent (in this example)
// of the button that was clicked
function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: I know it will work, but it is not working in some different file

Comment: As long as `file2` is called after `file`, and you're allowing your DOM to load, I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: @Leith I just noticed that `else` in the first file. My guess is that `file2` is getting run before that condition has been met. Hence why it won't work.

Comment: Yeah, right, its loading before it, what can I do to solve it?

Comment: @Leith, just use event delegation as I mentioned in my answer. Your files will operate on the same DOM, so just divide up the code into those files. I've updated my answer.

Comment: is using `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",` good idea?

Comment: There are lots of ways to wait for the DOM to load. That's one. You can [use defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script), or just add the script calls to just before the `</body>` tag. @Leith